# AWS Step Function: Catching Batch Transform Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine that includes createTransformJob.  When this step fails, the error seems to go to "Output" rather than "Exception", so I can't catch it in the "Catch" clause, even if I catch "States.ALL".  The state itself fails, causing the whole execution to stop there without going to the next step or the step specified in the Catch clause. Is there a way to force the error to go to "Exception"?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing for the failed State? If it's a Runtime error you can't catch it. Also giving your State Machine Definition will be helpful

Comment: This particular failure was because the TransformJobName wasn't unique because I forgot to change it.  The failure itself was easy enough to fix, but regardless the type of error, I want it to catch it so it can automatically perform necessary cleanup instead of just stopping there.

Comment: Did someone find on how to do this? Currently, the batch transform keeps on running for a max of 30 minutes even though there is an error. I would like to terminate it if there is some error.